Почему в данном случае код выведет 0 2 0
int x = 0;
std::cout << x << " ";
if (x == 0) {
    int x = 1;
    x *= 2;
    std::cout << x << " ";
}
std::cout << x;


Пропустил объявление ещё одного икса.

Фигурные скобки образуют блок.
Объявленная в нём переменная  int x является локальной для этого блока.
